# Truncate Text from Rich Text Editor - Umbraco 8

Tags: razor, tostring, truncate, umbraco8

Im trying to truncate the article text to display only the first 100 characters of the string.

```
    @item.Value("articleContent").ToString().Truncate(100) <a href="@item.Url">Read More..</a>
```

This works perfectly to truncate the string - but it displays the `<p>` tag at the begining.

This is what it looks like -

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquet sapien non posuere pretium... Read More..
```

How can I avoid displaying the HTML Tags?

Comment: That's kind of the point of using a RTE field, you should consider using a `Textarea` fieldType.
If you want to remove the html-tags from a RTE value you should probably use `HtmlAgilityPack` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just strip the HTML tags before the truncate

```
Regex.Replace(item.Value("articleContent"), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty).Truncate(100);
```